# Accessing inspector_agent.h in a node addon

Tags: c++, node.js, node-inspector, node.js-addon

I am writing a node native addon and I am trying to utilize some of the functionality in "inspector_agent.h". I have tried to import it as each of the following:

```
#include <inspector_agent.h>
#include <inspector.h>
#include <node_inspector.h>
```

with the compiler being unable to find the file in both cases. I am including v8.h and node.h in the same file, and it can find those. How can I import it? Alternatively, what headers from node are available to import? I am fully aware that the inspector_agent.h functionality is also available in the node core inspector module (experimental), but I need to call it from a different thread, so that's not particularly useful. I am using node 9.3.0 from the Arch repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find it. All the header files available for addons are in

```
~/.node-gyp/<version>/include/node/
```